# Can someone explain why electrons of n type(conduction band,higher energy),fall into holes in p type(valence band,lower energy) during forward bias?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronics

As I was learning semiconductor physics I learned that holes are deficiency of electrons.I also learned that the electrons from the n type material combine with the holes in p type and the electrons move along through these holes and conducts electricity in forward bias.

My doubt is that inspite of having higher energy of electrons due to its position in conduction band how are they able to fall into holes in p type which is in Valence band where the energy for electrons is lesser for a normal pn junction diode during forward biased condition.

Comment: Recombination and generation processes are central and essential to semiconductor physics.